# Storing 100k map markers in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm designing yet another "Find Objects near my location" web site and mobile app.
My requirements are:

- Store up to 100k objects;
- Query for objects that are close to the point (my location, city, etc). And other search criteria (like object type);
- Display results on the Google Maps with smooth performance.
- Let user filter objects by object time.

I'm thinking about using Google App Engine for this project.
**Could You recommend what would be the best data storage option for this?
And couple of words about dynamic data loading strategy.**

I kinda feel overwhelmed with options at the moment and looking for hints where should I continue my research.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to to assume that you are using the datastore. I'm not familiar with Google Cloud SQL (which I believe aims to offer MySQL-like features in the cloud), so I can't speak if it can do geospatial queries.

I've been looking into the whole "get locations in proximity of a location" problem for a while now. I have some good and bad news for you, unfortunately.

The best way to do the proximity search in the Google Environment is via the Search Service (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/ or find the JAVA link ). Reason being is that it supports a "Geopoint Field", and allows you to query in such a way.

Ok, cool, so there is support, right? However, "A query is complex if its query string includes the name of a geopoint field or at least one OR or NOT boolean operator". The free quota for Complex Search Queries are 100/day. Per 10,000 queries, it costs 60 cents. Depending on your application, this may be an issue.

I'm not too familar with the Google Maps API you might be able to pull off something like this :(https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3)

My current project/problem involves moving locations, and not "static" ones (stores, landmarks,etc). I've decided to go with Amazon's Dynamodb and they have a library which supports geospatial indexing : http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/09/05/announcing-amazon-dynamodb-geospatial-indexing/

Comment: Additionally, I moved from Dynamodb (due to an index restraint, which I believe they may of been fixed) to Postgresql, using the PostGIS spatial plugin, off of AmazonRDS.

I was able to get hibernate spatial setup with little issue. Make sure you set "hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" to false though.